# Switching from Raid1 to Raid10

Tags: raid, raid1, raid10

we are running a Dell Server with a PERC5i Raid card using a Raid1 setup. Now we are hitting a performance problem with our harddrive performance and think about switching to Raid10.

Which steps are necessary when switching from Raid1 to Raid10? Can I do this without a new installation of the system?

Thanks!
Jonas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Backup the server and test the
   backup
2. Update the server - BIOs, PERC
   firmware, disk firmware - everything
   (contact Dell support for help with
   that)
3. Go into OMSA (install OMSA if you
   don't have it - Dell support can
   provide a link)
4. In OMSA go to the Logical Disk, from
   the drop down menu choose
   "reconfigure" and if you have enough
   drives, it will let you choose the
   additional disks and a new raid
   level.

Plan for downtime - reconfig might take a while, and it's not recommended to do any data manipulation on the host during the reconfiguration.

Comment: Yep, that's the one drawback when migrating from RAID1 to RAID10 (compared to gogin from RAID0 to RAID01): you have to wipe the existing RAID1 array. It's worth the effort though :-)